# How to check file download SSH.NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I'm using SSH.NET library in a desktop application. How can I arrange to check the upload to the server if the connection is broken. I conducted a small experiment with the folder synchronization method, and when the connection is broken, it creates a file on SFTP server, and when the network appears, it starts downloading.

```
public void SynchronizeDirectories(string sourceDirectory, string sourceFolder)
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectToHost();
            var searchPattern = "*";
            var upLoadedFiles =
                sftpClient.SynchronizeDirectories(sourceFolder, sourceDirectory, searchPattern);

            foreach (var file in upLoadedFiles)
            {
                LoggerManager.InfoMessage($"File on sftp has been updated {file.Name}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LoggerManager.ErrorMessage("Error sftp server sync", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Maybe is there way to keep the file from being created until a full sync occurs?? Or WinScp style with creating file with .filepath extencion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to change about behaviour of the `SftpClient.SynchronizeDirectories`. In any case, the method offers no customization whatsoever. But you can reuse its code and modify it the way you like. SSH.NET is open source.

Or use [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) and its [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories), if you like how WinSCP implements the synchronization.

Comment: Thank's I changed code in SSH.NET SftpClient class for my needs. Perhaps I will make a pull request. So I added another extension (.tmp) if the file has not yet been uploaded to the server, when it was uploaded, then the extension is changed to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I created pull request to [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) several days ago –
[Added filepart (.tmp) extension #791](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/pull/791/commits/cf11a8f41393fca90abecfe95c39f77c60f06004)

I changed code in `SftpClient.cs` `InternalSynchronizeDirectories` method I added .tmp extension if file has not yet been uploaded to the server. Then extension is changed to the original when it was uploaded.